# Redrawing data table causes data lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've a test case where I need to reload table rows when the user changes input fields and clicks submit button. When the table is first initialized, table body is empty. And then I make a ReST call to get the JSON data and construct the tbody html. Problem I'm facing is that one of the column in the table is supposed to be visible. But since the html markup is being created after the table is initiated, the column that is supposed to be hidden is showing up. I tried to call the draw() function on the table API but that is causing the data to be lost. Is there any other way I can do this?

**HTML**

```
<p>

        <input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate"/><br/>
        <button type="button" id="refresh">Refresh</button>

    </p>

    <table id="myTable" style="width: 400px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="no-show">Col A</th>
                <th>Col B</th>
                <th>Col C</th>
                <th>Col D</th>
                <th>Col E</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>

    </table>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var table;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var table = $("#myTable").dataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "pageLength": 5,
            "pagingType": "simple",
            "info": false,
            "order": [[2, "desc"]],
            "aoColumnDefs":[
                {"aTargets": ["no-show"], "bVisible": false}
            ],
            "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json){
                $(".dataTables_filter, .dataTables_length").hide();

            }
        });

        refreshTable(table);


        $("#refresh").on('click', function(){
            refreshTable(table)
        });
    });



    function refreshTable(table)
    {
        var data = "startDate="+$("#startDate").val()+"&endDate="+$("#endDate").val();

        var url = "data.json";

        $.ajax({

            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(data){

                var tbodyHtml = "";

                for(var i=0; i< data.length ; i++)
                {
                    tbodyHtml += "<tr>";

                    tbodyHtml += "<td class='no-show'>"+data[i].eid+"</td>";
                    tbodyHtml += "<td>"+data[i].firstName+"</td>";
                    tbodyHtml += "<td>"+data[i].lastName+"</td>";
                    tbodyHtml += "<td>"+data[i].department+"</td>";
                    tbodyHtml += "<td>"+data[i].manager+"</td>";

                    tbodyHtml += "</tr>";
                }

                $("#myTable tbody").html(tbodyHtml);

                table.api().draw();

            }
        });


    }


</script>
```

P.S. the tbody html I've here is pretty basic. I actually have to do a bit of logic on the data before populating the table. That's why I didn't use Datatable's in built AJAX api.

Comment: What does the css class `no-show` look like?

Comment: @SteveWellens.. it's used for telling data table which columns to hide.. `{"aTargets": ["no-show"], "bVisible": false}`

Comment: @Rkodakandia - In other words...you don't have a CSS class?   Try adding one:  `<style> .no-show : { display: none; } </style>`

Comment: This won't work. You can't manipulate the html yourself because all the data and cached html is stored internally. Use the api to manipulate data, otherwise you would need to reinitialize the whole plugin this way

Comment: @charlietfl.. any pointers on which api functions to use other than the built in ajax processing?